# What is the scope of a #define'd variable?

Tags: c, scope, c-preprocessor

I am trying to use a preprocessor variable I declared in main.c in another **C** source file in the same project but I get a compile time error, included from main.c: undefined symbol 'mysymbol'. Now, what are the rules concerning the use of `#define` out side the file in which it is contained?

Comment: if you need to use it in more than one class you should define it in a header file, then include the header file in both source files.

Comment: @Hunter: "class"?  He's asking about C, not C++.  But even in C++, it should be "more than one source file".

Answer (score 9):

> Now, what are the rules concerning the use of #define out side the
>   file in which it is contained

A `#define` is not visible outside its file. The only way to make it visible outside the file where it is defined is to include that file.

So it looks like you should put it in a header included by both `main.c` and that other file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `#define` in a header, and `#include` it in all files where you want to reference it.